# Swap endian in pcm audio

Tags: c++, audio, endianness, pcm

I've made simply program to swap endian in PCM audio (2 channels, 48kHz, 24 bit), but only one channel is swapped correctly, second one is still little Endian (i've checked generated output in CoolEdit 2000). Could anybody give me some guidance what's wrong in my code?

```
inline int endian_swap(unsigned int x)
{
unsigned char c1, c2, c3, c4;

    c1 = x & 255;
    c2 = (x >> 8) & 255;
    c3 = (x >> 16) & 255;
    c4 = (x >> 24) & 255;

    return ((int)c1 << 24) + ((int)c2 << 16) + ((int)c3 << 8) + c4;
}

int main()
{

FILE *fpIn, *fpOut;
short x;

fpIn = fopen("audio.pcm", "rb");
fpOut = fopen("out.pcm", "wb");
int test = sizeof(short);

int count = 0;
int swaped = 0;

while( fread(&x, sizeof(int), 1, fpIn) == 1 )
    {
    swaped = endian_swap(x);

    fwrite(&swaped, sizeof(int), 1, fpOut);
    }

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Best regards!

Comment: How is `endian_swap()` implemented?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't add the endian_swap() before

Comment: With the combination of both bugs (mentioned by Oli Charlesworth and  mtrw), I'm surprised that either channel looked OK.

Answer (score 2):

You are reading in the file one `int` at a time.  But an `int` is probably either 16-bit or 32-bit.  You say you have 24-bit audio.

You should modify your code to read three `char` at a time, into a `char [3]` array.  You will then too modify your `swap_endian` function to operate on a `char [3]` (this is easy; just swap the contents of the first and last elements of the array!)

Comment: And don't forget that swapping the endianess of 24-bit values won't work if you pass those values to a function that's swapping 32-bit ints.

Answer (score 1):

You declared `short x`. Try declaring `unsigned int x`.

Comment: This is indeed an issue.  But it won't fix the main problem (see my answer).

Comment: @Oli - I assumed that the file actually contains `int`s, not `char[3]`s, just because I've never seen it done that way. Most interfaces end up giving a full 32-bit result, with the 24 data bits shifted to one end or the other. I imagine this is why one channel looked ok in the OP's first experiment. If the file really held `char[3]`s both channels would look mangled.

Comment: @mrtw: I don't mean that the file would literally contain `char [3]`s, it would contain `int24`s, but they don't exist as a native type in C!

Comment: @Oli - I've never seen a file containing `int24`s, though there's a first time for everything. I agree that if such a file existed, `char[3]` would be right way to deal with it. I'd be very surprised if an ADC delivered packed `int24`s because the MCU or whatever was dealing with the data would need to unpack it anyway. Easier to let the SPORT/SPI/whatever and its associated DMA engine put the data into word-aligned memory.

Comment: @mrtw: Neither have I, but then I've never worked with 24-bit PCM.  What you seem to be suggesting is that you'd be expecting the file to be 25% padding.

Comment: @Oli - Yes, exactly. That's the only way I've seen 24-bit audio stored in raw form. And based on the OP saying one channel was mangled with his existing code, that's what I'm guessing happened here.